# Why is supplying the hostname sometimes optional and otherwise not in psql?

Tags: postgresql

After having used `createuser` and `createdb` to create a user and database both called `teamcity` I wanted to log in. Using both of these commands, I never said anything about which host the database was running on, so I would assume that when using `psql` it would use the same settings. This is what happens if I do not supply a hostname:

```
$ psql -U teamcity
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "teamcity"
```

No password prompt and immediate failing. If I supply `-W` to force a prompt, the password does not work. I am logged in as a normal unix user, not the `postgres` user.

Now, if I supply `-h localhost` everything works as it should:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U teamcity
Password for user teamcity: 
Timing is on.
Line style is unicode.
Border style is 2.
Null display is "[NULL]".
Expanded display is used automatically.
psql (10.11 (Debian 10.11-1.pgdg80+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

localhost teamcity@teamcity=> \q
```

What can explain this behaviour? I assume some of the commands connect to the postgres using unix sockets and some using TCP, but it should be the same database, no matter, right, so why is the authentication failing in some cases?

Answer (score 2):

The default for all Postgres command line tools is to use "local" connections, i.e. unix sockets (unless this is "overruled" by [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)).

The next step in the authentication process is to look up if and how the user should authenticate - which is defined by the entries in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Most probably the default entry in `pg_hba.conf` says "all local connections are authenticated using peer" which is the default and is controlled by the following line:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

So `psql -U teamcity` tries to use a "local" connection and `pg_hba.conf` requires `peer` authentication for the user `teamcity` - most probably your current Linux user is not named `teamcity` and thus the authentication fails.

If you add `-h localhost` to the command line, a "host" connection using TCP is established, which is controlled by a different set of rules in `pg_hba.conf`.  Maybe our file contains something like:

```
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

which allows TCP connection from any client if, with any database user as long as the correct password is provided.

You probably ran `createuser` and `createdb` while being logged in as the `postgres` Linux user, and for that `peer` authentication succeeds as the Linux username matches the Postgres database username.